# How shall I understand the different outputs by `-A` and by `-e` of diff3?

Tags: text-processing, diff, version-control, ed, diff3

[diffutils' manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/manual/html_node/Marking-Conflicts.html#Marking-Conflicts) says, in `diff3 -A mine older yours`

> The ‘--show-all’ (‘-A’) option acts like the ‘-e’ option, except that it brackets conflicts, and it outputs all changes from `older` to `yours`, not just the unmerged changes.

I have three files, each with four lines of numbers

```
$ paste f1 f2 f3
0   0   1
2   1   2
2   3   3
4   5   6
```

Is it correct that there is no merged changes, so `-A` and `-e` should both output the unmerged changes only?

How shall I understand the following different outputs by `-A` and by `-e`? 
I guess that I lack some knowledge to understand the `ed` script generated by `-A`. For example, I am not sure what this command does at the end of the output by `-A`. Usually `a` command is followed by lines to be added, but there doesn't seem to be any line following the command:

```
0a
<<<<<<< f1
.
```

Thanks.

---

Among the changes from `f2` to `f3`, the unmerged changes are

```
$ diff3 -e f1 f2 f3
1,4c
1
2
3
6
.
```

All the changes from `f2` to `f3`, consisting of both unmerged and merged changes, are:

```
$ diff3 -A f1 f2 f3
4a
||||||| f2
0
1
3
5
=======
1
2
3
6
>>>>>>> f3
.
0a
<<<<<<< f1
.
```

Answer (score 3):

If you apply the `ed` script that `diff3 -A` produces to your original file, you will see what it actually does:

```
$ diff3 -A f[123] >script.ed
```

(I'm using `patch` here, but you could also have used `ed`, but then you would have had to add a command to the end of the script to either write the buffer back to file (`w`) or print it out on the terminal (`%p`))

```
$ patch f1 script.ed
Hmm...  Looks like an ed script to me...
Patching file f1 using Plan A...
done
```

```
$ cat f1
<<<<<<< f1
0
2
2
4
||||||| f2
0
1
3
5
=======
1
2
3
6
>>>>>>> f3
```

This shows that the edits to this bit of the file (which happens to be the *whole* file in this particular example) is a conflict (it is "bracketed" between `<<<<<<<` and `>>>>>>>`).  It shows you what the conflict is by giving you the contents of `f1` ("my file") followed by the contents in `f2` and `f3` ("old file" and "your file" respectively).

The difference between this and what `diff3 -e` produces is that the `ed` script produced by `diff3 -e` will transform `f1` into `f3`, ignoring possible conflicts in `f2`:

```
$ diff3 -e f[123] >script.ed
```

```
$ patch f1 script.ed
Hmm...  Looks like an ed script to me...
Patching file f1 using Plan A...
done
```

```
$ cat f1
1
2
3
6
```

So when the manual says that "it brackets conflicts", it means that it will insert these conflict markers into the resulting file if you apply the diff as a patch.

---

When it comes to *reading the diff*, it's a bit difficult if you don't know `ed`.

```
4a
||||||| f2
0
1
3
5
=======
1
2
3
6
>>>>>>> f3
.
0a
<<<<<<< f1
.
```

The last part, which you commented on,

```
0a
<<<<<<< f1
.
```

inserts the literal line `<<<<<<< f1` at the top of the file which is being edited. This way the diff itself does not have to contain the original contents of `f1` (the file being patched).